# vue-cli + webpack: where to include npm package js and css files?

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, npm-install, vue-cli

I'm trying to import an npm package into my vue-cli dev site. Here are the [instructions](http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.WWA9GNPytTZ) provided by the package website:

[image]

It says that it needs the css and js files to be included somewhere in the code. How would I go about doing this?

I'm guessing the css file is included by putting this in `App.vue`:

```
<style>
  @import '../node_modules/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css';
....
</style>
```

Is that right? How would I include the .js file? Inside `App.vue`, or `main.js`? I'm honestly not sure how the syntax for that would go either.

Here is my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/swiper.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="build/swiper.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working - in my `main.js` file, I've included the js and css files like this:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper'
import 'swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css'
```

As far as I can tell, this is correctly importing the npm package into the project for use in development and production.

Answer (score 0):

you can include these files in `build/index.html`like common js and css

```
<head> 
....
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="path_to_css/idangerous.swiper.css">
 <script defer src="path_to_js/idangerous.swiper-2.x.min.js"></script> 
.... 
</head>
```

Comment: This throws a 404 error in development mode, unfortunately.

Comment: you can take these two files into build foler,

Comment: sorry I see the code after you remind me, it is my fault; you should use relative path, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./swiper.min.css"><script src="./swiper.min.js"></script>`